# Using Graph API without depending on one User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-access-token, facebook-permissions

We are using Graph API for accessing public feed from our own Facebook Page.

What is the best way to obtain Access Token, so the requests are not dependant on one person's (my) User Access Token?

So after I leave the project, someone else can use the same token, without it being associated with me, but with the Page or a company instead?

Answer (score 0):

Page Tokens are always tied to a specific user, because you need a User Token to generate a Page Token. For a non-restricted Page, you can just use an App Access Token though. It has no relation to any user.

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: If you open your app's page on developers.facebook.com, and click on "Roles" on the left menu, you can see, that there have to be specific people assigned to the app. But I guess it's the only available solution :/

Comment: well, of course someone has to create the app ;) - but we are talking about tokens, and they are not tied to one specific user.